# How would I create this AS3 data structure in objective c?

Tags: objective-c, actionscript-3, data-structures

In AS3 if I wanted to quickly setup some data to work with, I would just do something like this...

```
static var playerData:Object = {position:{startX:200, startY:200}};
```

How would I create the same in Objective c?

Or..is there a better way to store a similar data structure in Obj-c?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be clear, I'm not an expert in Objective-C, so maybe some Objective-C guru can help you better than I can. But I think that you can use `NSMutableDictionary` to simulate the `Object` AS3 behaviour:

```
id playerData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
id position = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

[position setObject:@"200" forKey:@"startX"];
[position setObject:@"200" forKey:@"startY"];

[playerData setObject:position forKey:@"position"];
```

If in AS3 you access as:

```
playerData.position.startX
```

In Objective-C you can do something like this:

```
[[playerData objectForKey:@"position"] objectForKey:@"startX"];
```

Comment: Thanks, looking at what you put it occurred to me that perhaps the correct question would be is there a better way to store a similar data structure in obj-c other than just converting from the AS3 way, so I have edited my original question.

Comment: @Phil Ok, I hope someone can help you better than I did :)

Answer (score 1):

If it's something you'll use a lot maybe creating a custom class is a better way.

```
customClass <NSObject>

@property float startX
@property float startY
```

This way, you can use the dot just like in AS3:

customClassIstance.startX / startY

Let me know if you need further clarification.

Comment: Well I do a lot of dynamic referencing, such as playerData[elementType][type], where elementType and type are strings which I can put together.