# How to store constant data in Objective c?

Tags: objective-c, actionscript-3, data-structures, nsmutabledictionary, parse-platform

I'm a AS3 game developer who is trying to get his head around Obj-c. One of the things I'm not sure about with Obj-c is how to store game data. In AS3 I would just do something like this...

```
static var playerData:Object = {position:{startX:200, startY:200}};
```

Which I can easily access like this...

```
var x1:Number = playerData['Position']['startX'];
```

Or if I had multiple rows of data I could even do something like this...

```
myData["runOnFrame" + currentImageIndex]
```

Where I could access the object runOnFrame1, runOnFrame2 and so on.

I asked a question yesterday about how to setup the initial data structure above, and got some answers back...

[How would I create this AS3 data structure in objective c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11361155/how-would-i-create-this-as3-data-structure-in-objective-c)

But the way of setting up basic game data using a mutable dictionary seems a bit long winded to say the least.

So getting to the point of this question (finally), taking how I usually set things up in AS3 into account, what would be the best way for me to set up my game data in Obj-c? It would seem my options are...

1. Use the mutable dictionary approach in the above link
2. Set up a class with holds the data as basic vars, but then I'm not
       sure how I could access vars in that class dynamically (like my
       runOnFrame example)
3. Maybe use an array, but then I lose the labeling I think.

Or are there better ways? XML? I'm using Parse for this project, which seems great, and I'm wondering if I should just store my data directly using parse, so all data is accessed from the database right from the get-go, maybe that will be a good thing to start off with. Having said that I know there's going to be data that I want to hard code into the game, so any ideas on how best to do that will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Your observation of initializing a mutable dictionary item-by-item being too long is certainly correct. In fact, [the upcoming version of Objective C will provide better syntax for this task](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html):

```
NSDictionary *playerData = @{ @"position" : @{@"startX":@200, @"startY":@200} };
```

However, there is something you can do until this nice syntax becomes available: you can prepare a dictionary the long way, save it in a file as a *property list*, and replace the long initialization code with a single read of plist, the way [this answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3996273/335858) suggests:

```
playerData = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:@"playerdata.plst"];
```

Comment: When will that new syntax be available? Thanks for the info, the long way using the mutable dictionary still seems a lot of messing around, which I'm thinking if I'm going to do that, I might as well jus use XML or put the data straight into Parse perhaps, unless there's something else I'm missing.

Comment: @Phil I am not sure when Apple will integrate the new compiler with their Xcode line of tools, but the compiler itself is already available. I think we should see it as soon as Xcode 4 is released.

Comment: @Phil As far as the "long way" is concerned, try doing a small sample, save it to a file, and then edit the file manually to add more items that follow the same plist scheme. This should be easier than XML because of integration of property lists with `dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:` method.

Comment: @Phil I am not sure it's in 4.5 because I'm not usually trying out betas, but I would expect it to be not too far away, because the compiler is ready.